# Instanciar classe dentro de construtor

Tags: php, construtor, instanciar-objeto

Se eu instanciar várias classes em um construtor, por exemplo:

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();

    $this->loginModel = new \Application\Models\Login;
    $this->followModel = new \Application\Models\Follow;
    $this->likeModel = new \Application\Models\Like;
    $this->commentModel = new \Application\Models\Comment;
}

public function login()
{
    #code
}

public function follow()
{
    #code
}

public function like()
{
    #code
}

public function comment()
{
    #code
}
```

O código acima, toda vez que o usuário estiver utilizando a função de login, por exemplo, ele iniciará todas as classes né? Ou estou errado?

O correto seria instanciar elas dentro das respectivas funções?

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();

    $this->loginModel = new \Application\Models\Login;
}

public function login()
{
    $this->loginModel = new \Application\Models\Login;
}
```

O segundo exemplo de código, se o usuário usar o login, iniciará apenas o `login`. Mas e quanto ao processamento, isso influencia em alguma coisa?

Comment: O "correto" depende de cada caso: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/365119

Comment: O negativo talvez seja porque a pergunta não esteja muito clara, você diz que não tem bola de crsital, mas os outros também não tem. Então se acha que os outros devem escrever algo faça sua parte também antes de criticar. O negativo é uma crítica, as pessoas estão cansadas das pessoas cometerem os mesmos erros sempre e não comentam mais. Se voCê já levou vários negativos se esforce mais, leia e releia a pergunta várias vezes, se coloque no lugar de quem for ler e veja se twm tudo o que ela precisa. Não presuma nada, afinal você tem coisas na cabeça que a outra pessoa não tem, então escreva.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> O código acima, toda vez que o usuário estiver utilizando a função de login, por exemplo, ele iniciará todas as classes né? ou estou errado?

Irá instanciar vários objetos dessas classes dentro do construtor no momento que criar o objeto que tem esses métodos (a pergunta não mostra isso, mas só pode estar em uma classe).

> O correto seria instanciar elas dentro das respectivas funções?

Depende, a pergunta não diz o que precisa. Correto não é receita de bolo, correto depende de contexto, do que deseja fazer. Programar é tomar decisões de acordo com a necessidade. Se programar fosse fazer sempre as mesmas coisas sem precisar saber os requisitos então todos programas já teriam sido criados.

> O segundo exemplo de código, se o usuário usar o Login, iniciará apenas o login. Mas e quanto ao processamento, isso influencia em alguma coisa?

Na verdade este exemplo é confuso porque ele inicia um mesmo objeto em dois lugares, duvido que faça sentido. Ele cria de novo objeto que já existe então se o objeto original foi mexido e agora cria um novo objeto tudo será perdido e agora terá um objeto novo.

Na verdade este código parece ter muitos problemas conceituais, mesmo sem ver o resto do código. Não posso afirmar nada em específico porque a pergunta falta informações. [Construtores](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73530/101) sem parâmetros costumam ser errados.

Muitos exemplos de OOP em PHP que vejo por aí estão errados. Se tem um povo que não entende OOP é o de PHP, começando pelo fato dela ser uma linguagem de *script* e não faz sentido usar OOP nela. È verdade que andam transformando ela em linguagem *enterprise*, mas está pela metade.